# Tracking cursor C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, graph

I'm currently working on a class that will create an x,y graph according to given parameters when called, but I also want a description of each point in the x,y graph when the cursor hovers over it.

For example, if I generate a graph displaying market growth(year, amount, rate), and I hover over a certain point, I want a little box to appear and in it will be details about that point like the year, stocks, stock prices, position in graph, etc. I already finished the graph generator, but now I need help with this part.

How do I achieve this in C++?

Note -- I'm using Ubuntu.

Another note --- I created my graph without graphical libraries, and without any graphical functions. If you didn't understand my question at first, I'm basically asking 2 things: 1. How do I implement cursor tracking to my non-graphical graph with outer graphical libraries, and 2. if not possible, which library should I use to create a graph and how do I use them for cursor tracking?

Sorry for the confusion, it's just the first time I'm using graphics. I'm more of a "no external libraries" programmer.

Thanks.

Comment: It will be helpful to know what library you're using for graphics

Comment: Which toolkit do you use? gtkmm? Qt? Plain Xlib (*shudder*)? Something else entirely?

Comment: My graph isn't graphical. I forgot to add to my question that this is a double question. One, can I achieve cursor tracking without making my graph with graphical libraries and then using a graphical library for the tracking, and (2) if not possible, which graphical library is good for creating a graph, and how do I use it to track the cursor. Edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Using no external libraries at all doesn't make any sense.  Unless you are doing some sort of really low level embedded development, you will have managed to get a window open on the normal X11 display.  How did you get your window open?  Whatever you used for that will probably also have some ability to get mouse events.  It must be a somewhat graphical graph for people to be able to hover the mouse cursor over a point in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would opt for Qt since there is 3rd party library called [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) based on Qt which provides quite a lot of technical widgets including plotting ones (you might also be interested in Qwt [dedicated sub-forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/forums/23-Qwt) on qtcentre).

The solution for "txt-box on hover" effect is in fact very simple, you just have to set tooltip via [QWidget::setToolTip( const QString& )](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop) for the node widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a list of objects in the graph, and then do a "hit test" for each coordinate the cursor hovers over. This hit test basically entails iterating through your list seeing if the current coordinates fall on the object on the graph for that element.

Comment: Obviously this is what I need to do, no thinking here. My problem is how to do that.

Comment: Well, when you plot your objects, they will have a specific, known location and a specific, non-zero size. All you need to do is correlate those with the current coordinates. For example, if the object is a circle with radius 5 at (14, 24), then you need to see if `sqrt((14 - x) ** 2 + (24 - y) ** 2)` is less than or equal to 5, and then display the info if it is.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I would definitely choose such a solution over including external libraries. However, the only way I know to get the cursor position works only on Windows(GetCursorPos), and I'm working on Ubuntu. Any thoughts on how to get the cursor position on Linux?

Comment: I'm afraid that I haven't really done much graphical programming in Linux, but I would ask whatever toolkit I was using.

Answer (score -1):

If you're creating a graph via the console, I don't believe there is anyway for that console to know where your mouse is. A lot of the graphical functions you'd find in a language like Java just don't exist in C++, since the creators of C++ wanted these graphical libraries to be powerful, rather than portable. I second the recommendation for [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/), though I've never used it personally. It's the library I've seen most recommended elsewhere.